# SQL Server Job Failed - Account locked out

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We currently have a SQL Server 2012 job that fails to execute because of an account lock out. The message found within the Event Viewer is the following:

> SQL Error: The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.

The SQL Agent runs a local account and have verified it is not currently locked out within System Admin on the server. Have also verified that account is not locked out on the SQL Server box. The SQL Server job runs a SSIS package. If I run the SSIS package by itself the job will execute just fine. It is when it is executed via the job that it fails.

Has anyone else had a mysterious account locking problem with a SQL Server Job?

Comment: check the credentials against `sql agent service`, agent job normally is assigned to a `domain account`, as for backups and other types that will require network directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Right click sql agent job name -> view history -> check error. It gives exact details of what has gone wrong.
2. SSIS Jobs via SQL Agent needs proxy account, which contains credentials of SQL Server login. Hence `Security` -> `Credentials` and update the username and password.
3. Once done, make sure it is reflected in Proxy (SQL Server Agent -> `Proxies` -> `SSIS Package Execution`.
4. Make sure the referenced account is added under `Security` -> `Login`